# How to find command invoked path

Tags: bash, shell

I have exported my script to `PATH` variable. So from anywhere, I may invoke my script but I have to know from which path I am invoking the script.

Script present in the path `/home/raja/scps/shell/s1.sh`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/raja/scps/shell/s1.sh.
```

I will **run the script** as follows:

**1st example**:

```
root@raja-H97-D3H:/home/raja#s1.sh
```

I want to know the path: `/home/raja`

**2nd example**:

```
root@pmt-H97-D3H:/home/pmt/tmp/p1/p2#s1.sh
```

I want to know the path: `/home/pmt/tmp/p1/p2`

Comment: Small change in the last two lines as below



root@raja-H97-D3H:/home/raja/tmp/p1/p2#s1.sh



i want to know the path: /home/raja/tmp/p1/p2

Comment: That is an invalid close vote as I see it.

Comment: Are you trying to add the path to your script's directory to `PATH`? Are you trying to know the directory the script is in from within the script? Are you trying to know the directory the user is in from within the script?

Comment: You don't add the script itself to `PATH`, just the directory that contains the script.

Answer (score 3):

The current working directory from where the script was invoked is available in the `PWD` environment variable inside the script.

Consider this example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $PWD
```

Add it to your path, and invoke it from any directory. `$PWD` will have what you want.

This:

```
root@raja-H97-D3H:/home/raja# s1.sh
```

Would output `/home/raja`.

This:

```
root@pmt-H97-D3H:/home/pmt/tmp/p1/p2# s1.sh
```

Would output `/home/pmt/tmp/p1/p2`.

Also, you want to add the *directory* with the script to `$PATH`; not the script file itself. You should do this instead:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/raja/scps/shell
```

Comment: I think u didnt undersatand my questions clearly i know pwd will give present working directory. I may run the script from anywhere since i have exported my script to PATH variable. if i run from anywhere inside the calling script i have to the invoking path

Comment: @PMTRAJA my answer is consistent with the examples you show. I'm not sure I follow, can you please clarify?

Comment: what he want is create script once, and run it in any directory. I don't know how, but it seems a bad idea. what if you have two s1.sh, one is set as run in any dir and the other is in your working dir? what do you want shell to run?

Comment: @WayneSudo He already achieved that by adding the directory to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: 1. create one script.
2. export the script path to PATH.
3. run the script from anywhere
4. now i have to find the path where i am running the script. as sometimes i may run the script in $HOME directory  $HOME directory i have to knw some times $HOME/tmp/ directory these $HOME/tmp directory i have to knw

Comment: @PMTRAJA What do you mean by "invoking path"? Once you've added the directory that contains the script to your `PATH` (*not* the full path to the script itself), you can run that script from any directory, and `$PWD` contains the name of that directory. The path to the script does not change.

Comment: @PMTRAJA, for the steps you mentioned above, this solution works perfectly.